# Can I get info about a trigger time interval used to launch google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I recently discovered google apps script and it's amazing. I wrote a script that adds label to messages using logic that would not be available in normal GMail filters. I have then set that filter script to run on a time trigger, as unfortunately it is not possible to run it when message is received.

How my filter works:

```
function processInbox(age = "2.5h") {
  // process all recent threads in the Inbox
  var threads = GmailApp.search("newer_than:"+age+" in:inbox");
  Logger.log("Processing "+threads.length + " threads.");
  for (const thread of threads) {
    if(hasLabels(thread)) 
      continue;
    // get all messages in a given thread
    var messages = thread.getMessages();
    for (const message of messages) {
      if(matchesMyFilter(message)) {
        thread.addLabel(GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("My label"));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is an optional time parameter. Currently, the filter is set to run every 2 hours, so I check messages received in that timeframe with a little margin. However, if I want to set the trigger to run once per day, I would have to manually change the time in the script.

Is it possible to get information about the trigger used to launch the script and set the search range accordingly to the trigger timer interval?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the time-based trigger programmatically instead and pass the timeframe wanted/needed by using the `everyHours()` method.

```
function createTimeDrivenTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('processInbox')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(YOUR_NUMBER_HERE)
      .create();
}
```

However, unfortunately, you **cannot** modify an already existing trigger using provided methods since the [`Trigger`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger) class doesn't offer any options of setting any properties to a trigger, unless a new one is created.

#### Reference

- [Trigger Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger);
- [Managing triggers programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CacheService` for this. Just put some variable in cache for a `delay` time (in seconds) and then on every run (every minute, hour, anything you set up) just check if that cache record is expired:

```
function test(delaySec = 2.5*60*60) {
const cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
const delayed = cache.get('delayed') == 'yes'; // the values stored in cache are strings

if (delayed) return 0;
// otherwise - continue to execute function

// then in the end of the function
cache.put('delayed','yes', delaySec);

}
```

[Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache)